# Automatically clear the Azure App Service Temp folder after deploy

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service, storage, temp

Im using an Azure App Service for my ASP.NET project with the Shared tier plan, this has only 1GB of temp files allowed.

I use github actions to deploy my app to azure, each deployment create and store a zip file in the temp folder of my web app. After a few deployments my temp storage quota is full and I can't deploy anymore to my app, I get a 500 error.

The workaround is to manually delete the temp folder or restart the app (which clear the temp files) but this defeat the purpose of a CI/CD pipeline.

It is possible to automatically clear the temp folder files after every deployment?

Edit:
My github workflow

```
name: Build and deploy to Staging

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: AppName    # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'      # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET_VERSION: '7.0.*'                 # set this to the .NET Core version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "Staging" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release /p:PublishDir=${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Staging'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE_STAGING }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

Comment: You can have a step to perform a delete command right after the publish step.

Comment: @RogersonNazário Thank you for your response, I was thinking about this but I didn't know if it was possible or how to do it, do you have an example?

Comment: Can you please update the question with github yaml code to see whether it is possible?

Comment: Try add after `Deploy to Azure Web App` step add something like that:

`- name: temp clean`
`run: rm -rf ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}`

Comment: No it doesn't work, I get this `Run rm -rf .
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '.'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252022/discussion-between-rogerson-nazario-and-johnybro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by using a [post deployment action hook](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Post-Deployment-Action-Hooks) with a .bat file containing :

```
set folder="C:\path\to\your\dir"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```